# Majora's Mask: does the moon feel emotion?

Tags: video-games, the-legend-of-zelda, majoras-mask

In Majora's Mask, the scary-faced moon is always present overhead, looking down on Clocktown menacingly. Obviously, a standard moon does not show emotion, but this is no standard moon.

One of the first objectives in the game is to retrieve a "Moon's Tear", which we can see falling to Termina from the moon's eye. This is not proof, but could be an indicator that the moon might feel remorse. 
We also see at the end that the moon says

> I...I shall consume. Consume...Consume everything.

This indicates some semblance of sentience in the moon. So, is it noted anywhere that the moon might feel emotion?

Comment: That's no moon.

Comment: @Omegacron Then what is it? ([XKCD link](http://xkcd.com/1458/))

Comment: Double meaning too, lol. The moon is MUCH too small to be a "The Moon" moon

Comment: I think this question would belong on the Arqade site as it is a video gaming question.

Comment: are video games not allowed in sci-fi/fantasy?

Comment: Per [this discussion](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/319/can-i-ask-a-question-about-video-game-based-scifi-fantasy), I think this question is pertinent to this site.

Comment: If you never blinked while entering atmo, I think you'd shed some tears, too! Gotta keep them peepers moist.

Answer (score 3):

The moon in fact might have emotional capabilities, although the moon's tear may just be a fancy moon rock name. It does support the theory that the moon is sad or upset because of the disturbances caused by the skull kid. If you played the game, you will notice is the moon has an angry face. A likely reason is because it is being controlled by Majora's mask which is an evil power, which the people of Termina may not be able to not see, so they don't notice much wrong, so maybe only you have the magic capabilities to see it.

There may be a being a part of the original moon behind that creepy face which is sorrowful. Because of the fate of the beautiful world created by the goddesses whom in turn, created the moon.

Other than theories, there is not much in game evidence. This is how much of the game is structured. Because it may be supposed to have some short lived happiness overwhelmed by fear. The greatest element of fear is fear of the unknown because in you sub-conscious you assume the worst nightmarish possibility, it is mainly a gloomy game where you are discouraged by despair and helplessness. But still really awsome

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's anything in the game to back this up, but my personal interpretation has always been that the moon is being forced to do something against its will. Majora's Mask has the power to do incredible things and drive those it influences to the brink of insanity. It probably did that to the moon.

Then again, this moon is rather strange, what with the creepy face, and

> the dreamlike field and series of dungeons inside of it.

The people of Termina don't seem too concerned about it, which might indicate that the moon has always been this way, but then again, they don't seem to notice it crashing into them anyway. So it could be possible that it was somehow conjured by Majora. A strange moonlike object suddenly appearing might not phase the people in the slightest.

In either case, it's definitely being controlled by Majora, probably against its will. It certainly doesn't want to crash, that'd kill it. Hence, the tear.

Comment: Unfortunately, looking for in-game proof, not subjective opinion

Comment: There isn't any. I mentioned that. I was doing my best to deduce a logical answer from in-game clues. It's probably intentionally vague because the moon is only central to the story in the sense that it provides the deadline to work against. In other words, it's a gameplay element, not a story element.